# Objects eligible for garbage collection

Tags: java, scjp

This question was taken from [Kathy Sierra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kathy_Sierra) [SCJP 1.6](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0071591060). How many objects are eligible for garbage collections?

According to Kathy Sierra's answer, it is `C`. That means two objects are eligible for garbage collection. I have given the explanation of the answer. *But why is `c3` not eligible for [garbage collection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29) (GC)?*

```
class CardBoard {
    Short story = 200;
    CardBoard go(CardBoard cb) {
    cb = null;
    return cb;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    CardBoard c1 = new CardBoard();
    CardBoard c2 = new CardBoard();
    CardBoard c3 = c1.go(c2);
    c1 = null;
    // Do stuff
} }
```

When `// Do stuff` is reached, how many objects are eligible for GC?

- A: 0
- B: 1
- C: 2
- D: Compilation fails
- E: It is not possible to know
- F: An exception is thrown at runtime

Answer:

- C is correct. Only one CardBoard object (c1) is eligible, but it has an associated `Short` wrapper object that is also eligible.
- A, B, D, E, and F are incorrect based on the above. (Objective 7.4)

Comment: Strictly speaking `c3` can't be eligible for GC, because *it is not an object*. It is a variable could point to an object.

Comment: The correct answer is [all of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26645534/2711488)…

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No object ever existed that `c3` points to.  The constructor was only called twice, two objects, one each pointed to by `c1` and `c2`.  `c3` is just a reference, that has never been assigned anything but the null pointer.

The reference `c3`, that currently points to null, won't go out of scope and be removed from the stack until the closing brace at the end of the main method is crossed.

The object originally assigned to `c1` is unreachable because the `c1` reference was set to null, but the `c2` reference has not been changed, so the object assigned to it is still reachable from this scope via the `c2` reference.

Comment: It’s an interesting thing that there are so many tutorials and exercises discussing such things and all of them being wrong. The truth is, the JVM has no knowledge of the scope of local variables at all. In the past, this often implied that some references were not cleared despite being out of scope. Today, you might get surprised by the fact that object are collected despite being “in scope”, see [“finalize() called on strongly reachable object in Java 8”](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26642153/2711488)…

Comment: 1) the question is about java 6 2) without knowledge of what '//do stuff' may contain it's impossible to speculate about what optimization conclusions the compiler might make about the future reachability of the c2.

Comment: The rules between Java 6 and Java 8 haven’t changed. You can’t even preclude that such things happen in the actual Java 6 implementation, it’s just, that it hasn’t been discussed on SO so far. And if you assume that `// do stuff` may contain actions relevant to reachability, the correct answer would be that the question is incomplete. It just proves even more, how pointless such question are…

Answer (score 8):

Let's break this down line by line:

```
CardBoard c1 = new CardBoard();
```

We now have two objects, the `CardBoard` `c1` points at and the `Short` `c1.story`. Neither is available for GC as `c1` points at the `CardBoard` and the `story` variable of the `CardBoard` points at the `Short`...

```
CardBoard c2 = new CardBoard();
```

Similar to above, we now have four objects, none of which are available for GC.

```
CardBoard c3 = c1.go(c2);
```

We invoke the method go on the CardBoard pointed at by `c1`, passing the value of `c2` which is a reference to a `CardBoard` Object. We null the parameter, but Java is pass by value meaning that the `c2` variable itself is unaffected. We then return the nulled parameter. `c3` is `null`, `c1` and `c2` are unaffected. We still have 4 objects, none of which can be GC'd.

```
c1 = null;
```

We null `c1`. The `CardBoard` object which `c1` previously pointed at now has nothing pointing to it, and it can be GC'd. Because the `story` variable inside that `CardBoard` object is the only thing pointing at the `Short`, and because that `CardBoard` object is eligible for GC, the `Short` also becomes eligible for GC. This gives us 4 objects, 2 of which can be GC'd. The objects eligible for GC are the ones formerly referenced by `c1` and `c1.story`.

Answer (score 4):

`c3` is `null`, so there is clearly no Object there eligible for garbage collection.

Note that only two `CardBoard` objects are created, the two on these lines:

```
CardBoard c1 = new CardBoard();
CardBoard c2 = new CardBoard();
```

and after the reference juggling, only one of them is without references.

Answer (score 1):

The formally correct answer is that we don't know. And the reason we don't know is this line:

```
Short story = 200;
```

This compiles to the following byte code:

```
CardBoard();
Code:
   0: aload_0
   1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
   4: aload_0
   5: sipush        200
   8: invokestatic  #2                  // Method java/lang/Short.valueOf:(S)Ljava/lang/Short;
  11: putfield      #3                  // Field story:Ljava/lang/Short;
  14: return
```

Line 8 is the key here, `Short.valueOf()`, which returns a boxed equivalent of the primitive `200`. Let's look at the Javadoc of `Short.valueOf()`:

> This method will always cache values in the range -128 to 127,
>   inclusive, and may cache other values outside of this range.

200 is out of the "must cache" range, and thus it falls under "may cache". If it is cached, the value of `story` won't be eligible for GC when its containing `CardBoard` instance is. If it isn't cached, `story` will be unreachable and thus GCed.

To make the question unambiguous (and the proposed answer correct), the code should be amended like this:

```
Short story = new Short(200);
```

**Update:** The [1.6 Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Short.html#valueOf%28short%29) for `Short.valueOf()` is rather more cryptic than the 1.8 version I quoted, but the same logic applies: there is no way to tell just by looking at the code whether a new or a cached instance of `Short` will be returned.

Answer (score -1):

If you notice there are only two objects created in the code. c3 is never initialized to an object, it is a null reference. Hence, only one "object" eligible for garbage collection.